# Iterate 2D numpy array using for and while loops

Tags: python, numpy

## The objective of the code is to do the following:

1. Take an integer user input
2. Create a numpy array of 1s of that many number of rows and columns
3. Create a 1D array which using arange function which has the number of elements equal to the size of the array.
4. Multiply each of the elements of the 2D array with the elements of 1D array sequentially.
5. Print the final array.

I tried using iterating over different positions of the matrix using for and while loops.

```
size = int(input("Enter the matrix size:"))
one_matrix = np.ones((size, size), dtype=int)
y = np.size(one_matrix)
range_matrix = np.arange(1, y + 1)  
i = 0
for i in range(size):
    j = 0
    while j > 2:
        one_matrix[i][j] = range_matrix[i + j]
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

### I am getting output as:

All 1s instead of 1,2,3,....9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while condition is never satisfied as

> j = 0

and after that

> while j > 2

You can consider this solution:

> ```
> size = int(input("Enter the matrix size:"))
> one_matrix = np.ones((size, size), dtype=int)
> y = np.size(one_matrix)
> range_matrix = np.arange(1, y + 1)
>
> for i in range(y):
>     r = i // size
>     c = i % size
>     one_matrix[r][c] = range_matrix[i]
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works!!! But I have a question on my initial code I have used  the statement >>> j += 1. Which will increment the value of j till it exceeds the value of "size-1" (I wrote 2 by mistake). I would appreciate if you could correct my approach.

Comment: for your approach, do this:  `for i in range(size):
        j = 0
        while j < size:
            one_matrix[i][j] = range_matrix[i * size + j]
            j += 1
        i += 1 `

Comment: Thanks it works! I made a really silly mistake with the while loop. But how did you get this idea that using integer division and modulo can help you get matrix indices

Comment: it's Math :). You can draw the two arrays and map the position of each element inside, you shall see.

Comment: Yes I totally understand. Since I am new to coding I never thought about it. Thank you so much sir.